# $.confirm or confirm() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

what is the difference between calling $.confirm and confirm() in a plugin?

```
var jconfirm, Jconfirm;
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.confirm = function (options) {
        if(typeof options === 'undefined') options = {};
        /*
         *  Alias of jconfirm to emulate native confirm
         */
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($this.attr('href'))
                options['confirm'] = function () {
                    location.href = $this.attr('href');
                };
            $.confirm(options);
        });
        return $this;
    };
    $.confirm = function (options) { <-- HERE
        /*
         *  Alias of jconfirm
         */
        return jconfirm(options);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `$.confirm()` ≠ `confirm()`.

The `confirm()` is a built-in JavaScript function, that returns a boolean value:

[image]

The `$.confirm` is defined by the user / plugin using this way:

```
$.confirm = function () {
  // stuff
}

// or using $.fn.extend.
$.fn.extend({
    confirm: function(options) {
        var defaults = {
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Solution**

In your case of jConfirm, it uses a callback function. So whatever you do needs to be done using the callback function:

```
jConfirm('Some Title', 'Are you sure you want to delete your profile photo?', function(r) {
  // here `r` will be `true` or `false`.
  alert(r);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so what's the difference between $.myFunction and myFunction? Why should I use `$.` instead of the name of the function?

Comment: @Paul `$.` in front of any function means, it is a member function of the object `$`. Here, `$` is the jQuery object and `confirm` is an object of the `$`. Got it?

Comment: I will accept, don't worry, I am not totally sure what you mean : what does it change that I use `$.` instead of just calling the name of a function? I know `this` inside a plugin, or just calling the function, but I am not sure what `$.` does exactly.

Comment: Man, `$.something` belongs to `$` object. `$` is jQuery object or Object like `var Paul = {};`.

Comment: @Paul Kindly look at [`jQuery.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) and [`jQuery.fn.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/).

Comment: so `$.` is to "read" an already written jQuery function, and jQuery.fn is to "write" a new jQuery function? You cannot create a function $.something, it has to be already created inside jQuery? Or are they exactly the same?

Comment: Er... You confused me now. `so $. is to "read" an already written jQuery function` - You can use it as both getter and setter. Eg.,  `$.confirm = function () {}` - Write mode and `$.confirm("Hello")` - Read mode.

Comment: Ok well that makes sense with the code inside the plugin (getter/setter), but they use both ways, so there had to be a difference between the two I guess.